# JavaFX-2 BorderPane won't fill AnchorPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX and I have a StackPane within a BorderPane within a TitledPane. Like so:

TitledPane->AnchorPane->BorderPane->StackPane

The StackPane is placed in the center region of the BorderPane. My problem is that when I run the app, the BorderPane is not filling the AnchorPane that is associated with the TitledPane. I have tried the AnchorPane.setBottom(), setTop(), setLeft(), and setRight() properties, setting them to 0.0 and it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not see why you need a StackPane for centering in the BorderPane center, which does that out of the box. Have you tried to run you application together with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)? This usually gives a clear indication why the layout is not as expected. Fixing it is a different matter through.

Comment: post your or post image  i ll try to solve your problem